# How to convert objects into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have stored data in local storage in an array. Now I want to remove certain item from that array present in local storage.
For that first I have

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
var resturantid = localStorage.getItem('resturant_id');
var filtered = [];
for (var q = 0; q < items.length; q++) {

  if (items[q].resturantid == resturantid) {
    filtered.push(items[q]);
  }
}
console.log(typeof filtered, filtered);
```

output is   OBJECT

in console

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {name: "veg-momo", price: 12, count: 8, resturant: "Test Developer", resturantid: 2, …}
1: {name: "afdafasdf", price: 123, count: 4, resturant: "Test Developer", resturantid: 2, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

`typeof` gives me object and because of this I haven't been able to use `map` function as it says `array.map` is not a function.
I want these things to happen just to remove certain item in local storage key in which array is set.

Comment: Arrays are also objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @D.Pardal because of this i can't use array.map function.

Comment: What is `array` and where are you calling `array.map`? That's not in your code.

Comment: `typeof myArray` *always* gives "Object".  Don't let that dissuade you from using myArray.map.

Comment: Use `Array.isArray` if you want to know if a variable is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is something like **{0: {…}, 1: {…}}** you need to make an array of values like **[{...}, {...}]**! To do so use **Object.values()** and then apply **map()** or **filter()** or **reduce()** as per your program needs.

```js
let obj = Object.assign({},[{name: "veg-momo", price: 12, count: 8, resturant: "Test Developer", resturantid: 2}, {name: "afdafasdf", price: 123, count: 4, resturant: "Test Developer", resturantid: 2}]);

// obj.map(x => {console.log(x)}); //error: Uncaught TypeError: obj.map is not a function

Object.values(obj).map(x => console.log(x)); // Works!
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have to use filtered[0].name  etc
Because in HTML there is no object so you have to use this

But if you want to display in HTML you can use filtered[0].toString()
And print it

Comment: Please read [answer] for information on how to answer. Feel free to browse the other articles in the [help] to familiarize yourself with the site and how it works before using it.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an appropriate use of `map()`; this returns a new array with elements for all the original elements. Use `filter()` to return only the elements that satisfy a test.

```
var filtered = items.filter(item => item.restaurantid == restaurantid);
```

Your object is an array, so all the standard array methods should work for it.

Comment: Issues is with an object which is something like {0: {…}, 1: {…}}, not an array.

Comment: Where did you get that from? The question starts with "I have stored data in local storage in an array."

Comment: localStorage does not support the array

Comment: @ArunSaini The array is converted to JSON, and JSON supports both arrays and objects.